# Cannot POST /api/block

Tags: node.js

I am testing a GET & POST methods using ThunderClient extension and NodeJs, but I am unable to post the data ...it is showing cannot post data followed by relative path , (Get method is working perfectly) :

Here is my Index.js code:

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const Blockchain = require('./Blockchain');

const blockchain = new Blockchain();

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/api/block' , (req,res)=>{
    res.json(blockchain);
})

app.post('/api/mine' , (req,res)=>{

    const {data} = req.body;
    blockchain.addBlock({data});
    res.redirect('/api/block');
})

const PORT = 3000;

app.listen(PORT , ()=>{
    console.log("app is listening");
})
```

Comment: I guess that you didn't declared `post` on `/api/block`, but you didn't show the error

Comment: /api/block is for GET and its working perfectly but I am trying to send Post req on /api/mine but its raising a error

Comment: But you are redirecting to `POST` `/api/block`

Comment: ohh sorry for that.... its showing cannot post to /api/block .. so what should i do now ?

Comment: Try `res.redirect(303, '/api/block');`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Redirections#temporary_redirections

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default status code of the redirect is `302` which doesn't change
the request method.

Instead it stays as `POST`

To redirect as a `GET` method, you have to use `303` status code.

*Also see*

[`res.redirect`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.redirect)

[Temporary redirects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Redirections#temporary_redirections)